# How to change image src attribute based on 2 dropdown selections?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having issues with the below code. What I am trying to do is to preview an image based on what was selected in 2 of the dropdown options, before submitting form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#form-image1').on('onchange', function() var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
          var option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
          var option1selection = option1.options[option1.selectedIndex].value;
          var option2selection = option2.options[option2.selectedIndex].value;


          if (colourselection == "Blush " && patternselection == “Horizontal Stripes”) {
            $('#image1').attr('src', ‘https: //i.imgur.com/FHWSAJt.png’);
            )
          };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32" />
<select class="form-image1" id="option1" name="option1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select class="form-image1" id="option2" name="option2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the element that id is `form-image1`?

Comment: You can see from the formatted code that you have issues with your brackets. 
`)
          };` should be `} }); });`
Also it is .on("change") not on("onchange")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have jQuery, USE it

Here I use an object to match the selections and I use the common class to allow change of either dropdown

```js
const images = {
  "A1": "https://i.imgur.com/FHWSAJt.png",
  "B1": "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1666904566.4117/flat,128x,075,f-pad,128x128,f8f8f8.jpg",
  // ... 
}

$(function() { // on page load
  const defaultImage = $('#image1').attr('src'); // grab the image from the HTML
  $('.form-image1').on('change', function() { // any of the selects
    const opt1 = $("#option1").val();
    const opt2 = $("#option2").val();
    const image = images[`${opt1}${opt2}`] || defaultImage; // use default if not found
    $('#image1').attr('src', image);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="image1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32" />
<select class="form-image1" id="option1" name="option1">
  <option value="">Please select</optopn>
    <option value="A">Blush</option>
    <option value="B">Black</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select class="form-image1" id="option2" name="option2">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Horizontal Stripes</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

As for errors:

You had bracket issues.

```
  )   
};
```

should be

```
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Also it is `.on("change")` not `.on("onchange")`

Lastly `$('#form-image1')` is accessing an element with ID="form-image1" but you have only elements with CLASS="form-image1" and that needs to be accessed with a dot `$('.form-image1')`

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP will understand this answer but your answer is a beautiful decision. That's why I vote +1 from me :)

Comment: I used this code and it worked! Sorry for the errors as I am really new to jquery. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @mplungjan Hi, I added a div for the html but the jquery stopped working. Any reasons why? Below is the div: <div class="mobile"></div>

Comment: Not enough of information. Added where and how and why? Add an update to your question

Answer (score 0):

`$('#form-image1').on('onchange', function()` - Here `form-image1` id is not present in the HTML and also you have to modify `onchange` to `change`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#option1').on('change', function() {

    var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
    var option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
    var option1selection = option1.options[option1.selectedIndex].value;
    var option2selection = option2.options[option2.selectedIndex].value;

    // Based on the condition update the image source
    $('#image1').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/FHWSAJt.png');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="image1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32" />
<select class="form-image1" id="option1" name="option1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select class="form-image1" id="option2" name="option2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It also helps to format the code to see the mistakes

Comment: Your code does not actually USE the selections to change things